# Element <terracotta> does not allow attribute "storageStrategy"

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, ehcache, terracotta

Initial cause was Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:10: Element  does not allow attribute "storageStrategy".

org.xml.sax.SAXException: null:10: Element  does not allow attribute "storageStrategy".

I have used below jars for cache:

`ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar,ehcache-terracotta-2.6.11.jar and terracotta-toolkit-1.5-runtime-4.2.0.jar`

Comment: what's the content of your ehache configuration (ehcache.xml) ?

Comment: Is this an error you get when starting the client (ehcache.xml) or the server (tc-config.xml)? Please provide both configurations in order to get the proper answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!